# Differences between MathType and Equation Editor format in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, equations, equation-editor, microsoft-word-2008

I've been using [MathType Equation Editor](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/) to create Equations in Word. They key feature I have been using is the one where you type TeX equation and render it as an equation object. This generates objects that are of "MathType format". However, for purposes of submitting my document to a publisher, I was told I need these to be in "Equation Editor format". Is there a way to convert from MathType to this format?

I'm not sure what the difference between the formats is. All I did was install the MathType software in the above link and then inserted equations into my Word document using Insert -> Object -> Microsoft Equation Object.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.3 with Microsoft Word 2008 (Version 12.0.0).

Comment: The Equation Editor in MS Word has now been replaced by Unicodemath.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/linear-format-equations-using-unicodemath-and-latex-in-word-2e00618d-b1fd-49d8-8cb4-8d17f25754f8#__use_math_autocorrect  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2016/09/07/unicodemath/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the same format. My company, Design Science, makes the Equation Editor that comes with Microsoft Office on Mac and Windows since 1991 or so. MathType is the fancy version of Equation Editor with lots more features, including the TeX input feature you mention. Your publisher should be encouraged to mention that it accepts both MathType and Equation Editor equations as most publishers do. I suspect they have been getting documents containing MathType equations and handling them just fine all along.

By the way, the next version of MathType will feature compatibility with Mac Office 2011 which is due out later this month. As you may know, Microsoft left out Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) support in Office 2008 but they are bringing it back in this new version. That means MathType will have more commands like it has in Office 2004. In particular, you will be able to insert new equations without going through the Insert Object process.

Comment: Isn't there some little thingy in the document that says which editor to use for the equation -- say, a GUID for the object type? (Though I suppose maybe MathType uses the same GUID there as Equation Editor, which would be one way of avoiding the issue, though it would make it tricky to test things with both pieces of software on the same machine...)

Comment: Actually, I just installed MathType 6 in "trial" mode, and what you say doesn't match what it says in the "Comparing ... > Collaborating with Equation Editor Users" section in the help file, nor does it match the [MathType vs. EquationEditor](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/MathType/faqs.htm#mt_v_ee) section of your FAQ...